# Replaces id with a value from another table

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables:

```
Table Users

UserId     Name
1          John
2          Alice
3          Tom
4          Charles
```

and

```
Table Clients

Id         Name1          Name2      Name3
1            1              3          4
2            2              1          3
```

I would like to make a SQL query where for

```
Clients.Id = 1
```

the results are like:

```
Id         Name1          Name2       Name3
1          John            Tom       Charles
```

Using INNER JOIN I am able to do that for each column from Clients but not for the whole record (all three columns).

Comment: What you should do is normalise your data structures. Then this won't be such a pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join table `users` thrice on table `client`.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        b.name name1,
        c.name name2,
        d.name name3
FROM    clients a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.name1 = b.userID
        INNER JOIN users c
            ON a.name2 = c.userID
        INNER JOIN users d
            ON a.name3 = d.userID
WHERE   a.ID = 1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2f5b/5)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to the Users table once for each name.  Given you have 3 columns, it is likely one or more may be nullable, so you're more likely to want LEFT JOINs than INNER JOINs.

```
   select c.id, u1.name name1, u2.name name2, u3.name name3
     from Clients c
left join Users u1 on u1.UserId = c.name1
left join Users u2 on u2.UserId = c.name2
left join Users u3 on u3.UserId = c.name3
    where c.Id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option which doesn't require excessive join

```
SELECT c.Id, MAX(CASE WHEN u.UserID = c.Name1 THEN u.Name END) AS Name1,
             MAX(CASE WHEN u.UserID = c.Name2 THEN u.Name END) AS Name2,
             MAX(CASE WHEN u.UserID = c.Name3 THEN u.Name END) AS Name3
FROM dbo.Users u JOIN dbo.Clients c ON u.UserId IN (c.Name1, c.Name2, c.Name3)
WHERE c.Id = 1
GROUP BY c.Id
```